# Need the name of the OCX file for the DLL

Tags: .net, vb.net, ocx

I have a .Net project which has the following dlls:

- AxInterop.Crystal.dll ( comctl32.ocx )
- AxInterop.MSACAL.dll
- AxInterop.MSDBGrid.dll
- AxInterop.MSFlexGridLib.dll

I need to register the OCX to run my project. Can anyone help me out to find the names of the OCX file?

Thanks

Comment: You've listed 4 DLLs. What are they? Are they your OCXs? And what is comctl32.ocx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are VB6 controls from the previous century.  You need to find a machine that still has them, look in c:\windows\system32.  The .ocx/.dll file names ought to be reasonably close.  The ones I know are comctl32.ocx, mscal.ocx, dbgrid32.ocx and msflxgrd.ocx.  Getting Crystal Reports going should be difficult, it was never an integral part of VB6 and requires a bunch of DLLs.  These controls also have licensing verification, you won't be able to use them in design mode.  That requires a VS6 or VB6 license.  You can only get a VS6 license at an auction site like eBay, VB6 is available through an MSDN subscription.

If you get the creeping feeling that this software is getting hard to maintain then you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried REGSVR32

```
To register a module, you must provide a binary name.

Usage: regsvr32 [/u] [/s] [/n] [/i[:cmdline]] dllname
/u -    Unregister server
/s -    Silent; display no message boxes
/i -    Call DllInstall passing it an optional [cmdline]; when used with /u calls dll uninstall
/n -    do not call DllRegisterServer; this option must be used with /i
```

Comment: Am able to add reference in my project but in run time am getting the class not register exception.AxInterop.Crystal.dll ( comctl32.ocx )i tried this am clear the exception.so only am asking the other ocx file names